# Retrieving a datetime value from a sql table to dataframe using sqlalchemy

Tags: python, sql-server, pandas, sqlalchemy

I'm trying to retrieve a table into a dataframe but I'm getting a "ValueError: hour must be in 0..23".

Here is my code :

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
import pyodbc
import pandas as pd

SERVER = '(local)'
DATABASE = 'Projects'
DRIVER = 'SQL Server' 
DATABASE_CONNECTION = f'mssql://@{SERVER}/{DATABASE}?driver={DRIVER}'

engine = create_engine(DATABASE_CONNECTION)
connection = engine.connect()

data = pd.read_sql_query('select TOP 1 * from PRODSYNTHESIS',connection)
#ValueError: hour must be in 0..23

connection.close()
engine.dispose()
```

[table schema](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NDPVK.jpg)

My understanding is that I should probably be using python's datetime module to handle this datatype but not sure exactly how to get there. All other solutions I've found relate to the dateframe itself not the data type coming through from sql.

Comment: As a side question, why are you using `TOP 1` without an `ORDER BY`? Without an `ORDER BY` that might as well say "Return an arbitrary row from the table."

Comment: No specific reason to use TOP 1. Was just limiting the number of rows returned by the query.

Comment: Then introduce an `ORDER BY`. You won't get consistent results without one.

Comment: Good point. Will keep in mind for future debugs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure, but you can always woraround by converting the date to an ISO8601 string in the query itself.  EG:

```
data = pd.read_sql_query('select TOP 1 Project_id, Project_name, convert(varchar(23), Date_results, 126) Date_results, P_Injecte from PRODSYNTHESIS',connection)
```

Comment: Thanks! That works but as you said returns a string ie.2019-09-20T01:10:00. Do you know why the conversion is necessary? Why can't it pass through as such? In any case, the datetime library has a .isoformat() method which looks like I could use later in the code.

Comment: I do not.  But you might try with an updated ODBC driver.  The one you are using hasn’t been updated in almost 20 years and is a Legacy Windows component.   See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/download-odbc-driver-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: Good point. I was testing this on a old database and didn't even think this could affect the ORM.